# Flex: 1 Doesn't Fill Angular Layout Div Vertically

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox

I'm working on a sidebar using Angular and Flex. It's app-sidebar within the following layout Angular component:

```
<div fxlayout="row" fxFill>
    <app-sidebar fxLayout="column" fxFlex="10%"></app-sidebar>
    <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="100">
        <app-top-navbar class="navbar-component" fxLayout="column"></app-top-navbar>
        <div class="content" fxLayout="column" fxFlex>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the sidebar to fill the page vertically, the  list items within evenly spaced between that expanse. But I'm not having any luck... I've made a simplified version in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zxcm4enw/5/). You can see that it stretches horizontally (great, as I want it to fill that 10% of the greater layout), but it doesn't go to the bottom of the page.

I'm new to Angular and Flex, so any help would be appreciated. Here's the Fiddle code (if it makes a difference, anchors are used, because I also have icons not included):

```css
:host {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1 1 100%;
}

#sidebar-cont-div{
    display: flex;
    flex:1;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#navbar-content-container{
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    flex-direction: column;
} 

#main-navbar {
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50px 20px 20px 50px;
    text-align:center;
}

#nav-list {
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex: 1;
    margin: auto;
    min-width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id = "sidebar-cont-div">
 <nav id="main-navbar">
  <div id="navbar-content-container">
    <a href="#">
     <h1 id="sidebar-logo">Project<br>Dash</h1>
    </a>
   <ul id="nav-list">
    <li class="sidebar-item" role="presentation">
     <a href="#">
         <span>Overview</span>
     </a>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-item" role="presentation">
     <a href="#">
      <span>Project Record</span>
     </a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
please try like this 

body , html {
  height:100% ;
  margin : 0px ;
}

#sidebar-cont-div{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height:100%
}

#main-navbar {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg,rgba(127,162,137,0.82) 20%,rgba(39,86,94,0.92));
    border-radius: 50px 20px 20px 50px;
    text-align:center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

You can use the rest of the style as it is.By using the styles above your side nav will strech vertically.

working sample in stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-aqedvi

Comment: Ah, that works pretty well - thanks! One issue though, it stretches far past the initial screen size (you have to scroll down quite a bit to reach the bottom of the bar). Any ideas?

Comment: hmm, nothing seemed to change, same problem.

Comment: for me it is working. i missed to add semi colon after height:100%. may be that is the reason

Comment: added stackblitz link to answer

Comment: yea, still not working for me, maybe it's another component in the project. Thanks anyway, appreciate the help